# URI::InvalidURIError (URI must be ascii only)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a legacy rails 3.2 app, when I try to hit a route with a none-ascii char e.g; `example.com/city/bergstraße` then I get the following error:

```
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:20:in `split'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:72:in `parse'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/common.rb:226:in `parse'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb:91:in `block in redirection_proc'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
...
```

**The problem is, that I get this error before hitting any controller**, so I just wonder where can I catch this error to parse and fix the URL? thanks.

P.S: please have a look to the stacktrace before pointing me to any previous post.

Comment: @BugHunter, this is different because the error is not pointing to any function inside the app.

Comment: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12852

Comment: @tokhi, my bad, I thought you are trying to use URI module.

Comment: Not sure if this applies to your case, but you might find this helpful: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/catching-json-parse-errors-with-custom-middleware

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how you would actually create a request with an invalid URI, as most browsers will actually automatically encode the URI. Is this behavior triggered by a functional test or adhoc testing with cURL?

Comment: @max Yeah true browsers encode the URL, I just figured out that there are similar routes in the app which get encoded properly, but not sure why this one fails, I have to investigate a bit more.

Comment: Does this "bug" really have enough real world impact though to merit it?

Comment: @max I dont think so, but we have got a SEO guy who is insisting that it has to be fixed :)

Comment: A snakeoil salesman that insists you add UTF-8 support to a protocol that does not support it (facepalm). I feel for you.

Comment: I appreciate it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) a URI may contain only a subset of ASCII characters.

To provide a valid URI the non-ASCII characters should be escaped:

```
irb(main):008:0> URI.parse "example.com/city/#{URI.encode('bergstraße')}"
=> #<URI::Generic example.com/city/bergstra%C3%9Fe>
```

> The problem is, that I get this error before hitting any controller,
>   so I just wonder where can I catch this error to parse and fix the
>   URL?

The problem is you should not really be catching this error. Your rails server should not be responsible for responding to bad or malformed requests.

While you could attempt to write a piece of middleware to hack around the issue you should instead figure out why the clients are sending requests for an invalid URI.

If they are originating from your own application make sure you are escaping slug columns properly and not just creating urls with string interpolation. The [stringex](https://github.com/rsl/stringex) gem or [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) are your friends here.