# URI must be ascii only

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, uri

I'm creating a scraping program using Ruby

I will ask a question because a program that used to work without problems has stopped working.

When reading Japanese
The error that appears is the title error

```
`split': URI must be ascii only "https://www.google.com/complete/search?h1=ja&output=toolbar&q=\u4FDD\u967A" (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

as a place to wake up

```
doc = REXML::Document.new(open(url).read.encode("UTF-8"))
```

here is the code

I think it is necessary to change the URI encoding to ASCII.
I don’t know the best way to do it.

info

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

Thanks

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50157965/uriinvalidurierror-uri-must-be-ascii-only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849219/ruby-uriinvalidurierror-uri-must-be-ascii-only

Comment: thanks, but i already seen this topics bad fix this issue